# Injecting UI control into ScrollViewer programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Xaml

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="_ScrollViwer" />
```

Code behind

```
Image image = new Image();
_ScrollViwer.Children.Add(image);
```

Error

> ScrollViewer' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no accessible extension method Children'

Answer (score 1):

> Injecting UI control into ScrollViewer programmatically

`ScrollViewer` is not Panel, if you want to add `Image` into `ScrollViewer`, please pass it to ScrollViewer's content. And if you want to add more controls into `ScrollViewer`, you need use panel to package elements.

For example

```
Image image = new Image();
Image image1 = new Image();
var stackpanel = new StackPanel()
{
    Children =
    {
        image,
        image1
    }
};
_ScrollViwer.Content = stackpanel;
```